# Alternative method in Bash for checking if file is present

Tags: bash

I am currently running a script (check_files.sh) that may or may not produce match* files (eg. match1.txt, match2.txt, etc.  I then want to go on to run an R script on the produced match* files.

However, before I run the R script, I have tried a line in my script which checks if the files are present.

```
if [ -s match* ]
            then
            for f in match*
            do
                Rscript --vanilla format_matches.R ${f}
                rm match*
            done
else
            echo "No matches present"
fi
```

However, I keep getting an error message (as there are often a lot of match files producted):

```
./check_files.sh: line 52: [: too many arguments
```

Is there an alternative to [ -s match* ] which would not throw up the error message?  I take it that the error message appears as there are multiple match* files produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect filenames with spaces, this is a bit ugly but robust:

```
found=0
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'match*' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd $'\0' f
do 
    found=1
    Rscript --vanilla format_matches.R "$f"
    rm "$f"
done

if [ "$found" -eq 0 ]; then
    >&2 echo "No matches present"
fi
```

Comment: This will not work if the filenames contain newlines or backslash escapes. Consider using `find … -exec bash -c "script"` form instead of piping the output of `find`.

Comment: Backslashes and newlines on file names? Serious question, has that ever happened?

Comment: Yes. File names are user input to this program. Don't trust user input.

Comment: I fixed your original loop so it can handle newlines and backslashes correctly. `-print0` and `-d $'\0'` take care of newlines, `read -r` takes care of backslashes, and `IFS=` ensures leading whitespace are preserved.

Answer (score 2):

You could change your logic to the following:

```
found=0
for f in match*; do
    [ -e "$f" ] || continue
    found=1
    Rscript --vanilla format_matches.R "$f"
    rm "$f"
done

if [ "$found" -eq 0 ]; then
    >&2 echo "No matches present"
fi
```

Comment: This works as long as there are no spaces on the file names.

Comment: I tried this, but on occassions where no match* files are produced, I get this error: `cannot open file 'matches*': No such file or directory`

Comment: This is incorrect because `match*` expands to `match*` (the identity) when there are no matching files. Thus, the loop would execute anyway. The `nullglob` bash extension would be one way to make this work. Alternatively, just testing if the matched file exists within the loop would also work.

Comment: True @kojiro, fixed with the later mentioned approach

Comment: In response to my error message above - you are correct kojiro, this was in fact refering to the R script.  

If there were no files in existance, the literal argument `match*` was being called into R.

To fix this I put at the start of my R script:
`if (nchar(args)<7) {
  stop("No matches for format_snpmatchesscript", call.=FALSE)
} else if (nchar(args)>7) {
#scriptcontent
}`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative to [ -s match* ] which would not throw up the error message?

The following works for my example file match1.txt

```
if [ -f ~/match* ]; then
  echo "yeha"
fi
```